# OK I separated my content from my presentation, now what can I do with all that content?

Tags: html, css, latex, semantic-markup

HTML separates content from presentation (by using CSS for presentation and making HTML elements usually semantic), but LaTeX does not. What do people actually do with HTML that can't be done with LaTeX, that is a result of the fact that the presentation attributes have been separated out?

I don't *think* "display it in web pages" is an answer because that is a result of HTML being a markup language and TeX being a programming language (ie more complicated and harder to implement). But maybe I am wrong about that.

As another example of the kind of thing I'm asking about, I used a cirtuit diagramming tool once that used a single postscript file both to store the circuit semantically *and* to display it... a fairly impressive feat I thought. I'm wondering if anyone does that sort of thing with HTML -- uses the HTML to store machine-readable information, and CSS to present it in an automated way. (instead of also generating the HTML as part of the presentations like most websites do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seperating content from presentation doesn't allow you to do more, it allows you to do what you were already doing *cleaner*. So you can't do more with one than the other, but the *ease* with which you create and maintain the same thing will differ with the different approaches.

The same sort of principle applies to the concept of seperating blocks of code into reusable units, often called *functions*. Functions don't allow you to do any more than what you could do without functions. You can do everything without functions that you can do with them. But does that mean people don't *need* functions? No; try writing a nontrivial program without them.

Comment: That's an interesting point about functions. LaTeX does allow you to break things up pretty well (even more flexibly than HTML, really), but it's unclear whether they should be broken up semantically or presentationally (ie there are commands named `\em` for emphasis (semantic) and `\ttfamily` for setting the font (presentation)).

Answer (score 0):

HTML and LaTeX are both about letting authors get on with the business of writing without thinking much about how the final output looks. Contrast with a WYSIWIG system like Word or a page layout system where you are tempted to tweak how things *look* instead of focusing on what you are *writing*.

Answer (score 0):

You're falling into a trap by comparing LaTeX to HTML & CSS like that. With a single LaTeX document and a single HTML document you wont see any real gains either way other than familiarity. Additionally, it's not HTML & CSS; it's HTML, CSS & JavaScript.

The advantage to separating content from style from interaction (MVC pattern anyone?) is that when you need to *duplicate* something, it goes much faster. Once you've got the styling done with CSS, and the interactions done with JavaScript, you can reuse the CSS and JS infinitely many times with different HTML. The focus can be on the content, not on making it look right.